# calling anonymous function with underscore notation

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

I'm practicing the tricks with `_` notations in `anonymous functions` in scala.

I have this code (beginning isn't relevant for our case):

```
.map(some_data => SomeObj.do_some(some_data.some_field))
```

And i'm wondering if i can use `_` underscore notation here,

do something like:

```
.map(SomeObj.do_some(_.some_field)) # it doesn't work..
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempted syntax would be equivalent to `.map(SomeObj.do_some(some_data => some_data.some_field))`. Scala wouldn't know where to "insert" the parameter, where to wrap the expression in a function: it always does it at the innermost level.

Comment: That is how it was to me, but somehow it is not _always_ like that. 
For instance `Seq("foo").map(Some(_))` does compile. And so does `Seq("foo").map(new Foo().foo(_))`, but _not_ `Seq(new Foo("bar")).map(new Foo.foo(_.str))`

Comment: @Dima No, it's always like that, including your examples. "The innermost level" just can't consist of `_` on its own, so it'll be `Some(_)` which becomes `x => Some(x)` (and entire `new Foo().foo(_)` in the second example).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov ah, thanks! Makes sense ... So, no, not "always": rather "always except when innermost level is just `_`" :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use only once (`anonymous-function`) per partial function. But when they are recursively called, it is ambiguous to know where to place `_`. Hence you get error.